# UNIX time moment()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the UNIX time from *uptime* to go into the `moment()` tag, can't seem to do it.

```
let uptime = Math.round(Date.now()/1000) - globals.fxRunner.tsChildStarted;
let uptime2 = moment(${uptime}).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: `${uptime}` should just be `uptime`. Why would you put a variable inside braces like that?

Comment: Aren't you getting a syntax error in the console because of that?

Comment: I've tried that but it returns with Uptime = 4 and Uptime2 = 19:00:00.  Uptime2 should be 00:00:04...?

Comment: In this case, 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you divided `Date.now()` by `1000`, `uptime` is a time in seconds, but `moment()` expect the argument to be milliseconds. You need to multiply by `1000`.

```
let uptime2 = moment(uptime * 1000).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

But this is treated as a time in UTC, but you're formatting in your local time zone, so it will be off by 5 hours. You need to use UTC mode to get the output in UTC.

```
let uptime2 = moment.utc(uptime * 1000).format('HH:mm:ss');
```